# Rendering newsfeed as per Facebook user interface

Tags: php, css, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a facebook application that fetches the newsfeed of the logged in users and renders it. Currently, I am using iframe and I use PHP SDK to call the Graph API to fetch the posts and render them (generate on server side via PHP). To emulate the facbeook like look and feel, I mimicked their styles on which I am somewhat successful but not very much.

I am wondering is there a way in Facebook API to do the same for me? I read about the FBML but there is a deprecation warning along with a notice that they are gradually moving things towards their Javascript SDK.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are narrowed to what XFBML (The Javascript API) offers you.

I had the same problem a while ago and this site saved me - http://devtacular.com/articles/bkonrad/how-to-style-an-application-like-facebook/

There are some basic styles that are used by facebook.

Good luck.